# boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator: Wrong case

Tags: c++, unix, boost-filesystem

I use this code as c++ directory walker in order to obtain all files contents in a directory:

```
boost::filesystem::path current_dir(DAT_PATH); 
for (boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator iter(current_dir), end;
        iter != end;
        ++iter)
{
    std::string name = iter->path().filename().string(); //Wrong case
}
```

The problem is that the name's case is wrong: a file named 001A22b will be out lower-case.
How to fix this?
I'm experiencing this on ubuntu 12.04, boost version 1.48.0.2